# Refreshing table structures, views, functions and sps from one instance to another instance

Tags: sql-server, database

I have one PROD server database and STG server database.
I need to refresh the STG server database table structures (No Data), Views, Functions and SPs from the PROD server database.

What is the approach and how can we automate this?

Answer (score 0):

You can script it, but your life will be simpler if you just use a good comparison tool. Red-Gate's SQL Compare is excellent and easy to automate. I suggest you check it out.